# Error missing right parenthesis Oracle DB table creation failed

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

this is my first time ever using oracle db. I have been trying to create my first table and for some reason I am getting an error that says I am missing a parenthesis. I have checked to make sure I was not missing a parenthesis and clearly there is some other issue with my statement.

```
 CREATE TABLE hr.Mitch_Employee_Motors (
 empid INT(4) PRIMARY KEY, 
 empname VARCHAR2(10),
 empaddress VARCHAR2(10),
 empsalary NUMBER(8,2), 
 deptno NUMBER(4,0));
```

What am I doing wrong? This seems to be correct according to every resource I have found online.

Comment: @AaronDietz - please make this an answer. And `INT` is fine. Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021

Comment: Do you really need to limit the size of the `EMPID` field? Then don't use `INT`, use `NUMBER(4,0)`. There is really no benefit to `INT` in Oracle, it is simply mapped to `NUMBER(38,0)` anyway.

Comment: You guys are all awesome and ovbiously that immediately worked.. My "Instructor" gave us a list of specifications for the table and that row was supposed to be a 4 digit integer and he later specified a 4 digit number.. so I don't know what his intention was. There is no way to format an integer to have exactly 4 numbers correct? i.e "0000" rather than "0"

Comment: For a four digit number use `number(4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Mitch_Employee_Motors (
 empid INTeger PRIMARY KEY, 
 empname VARCHAR2(10),
 empaddress VARCHAR2(10),
 empsalary NUMBER(8,2), 
 deptno NUMBER(4,0));
```

Answer (score 1):

**INTEGER(4)** is not a valid datatype. This is probably what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE hr.Mitch_Employee_Motors (
empid NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY, 
empname VARCHAR2(10),
empaddress VARCHAR2(10),
empsalary NUMBER(8,2), 
deptno NUMBER(4,0));
```

Comment: I believe this answer is closer to the original intent, since it preserves the limitation on the number of digits permitted in the `empid` column. Getting my vote anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's just `INT`, remove the `(4)` to avoid the error.

`INT` has no length/precision/scale, it is a set range.

It's worth noting that `INT` in Oracle isn't a true `INT` however, and it actually maps to `NUMBER(38,0)`.  So perhaps you want `NUMBER(4)` instead. (Credit to mathguy)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021